# Marketplace submission fails but with no errors in it

Tags: magento2, marketplace, magento2marketplace, submission

I try to submit a module to the marketplace but it fails. When I want to see the reason it fails, I get no relevant JSON back. What can I do?

The JSON returned is: {"tool":"phpcs","status":"FAIL","reports":[]}

Comment: Try to re-submit this one.

Comment: what do you mean by this one? i see no link or anything similar in your answer